# Is there any way to calculate running total with condition in Redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift, cumulative-sum

I'm running a volume availability model for a package center at Redshift. In this table column B shows arrived volume at every hour. The shift starts at 1700 and ends at midnight. During that time they can process 50K packages every hour(column C).I have the table with first three column, and I'm wondering if there is any way to calculate column D at Redshift?

[image: Please click here to review the data]

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow =) Please add more details to your question so it is easier for the rest of the community to help you: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi Victor,
To make it more clear. I'm trying to calculate column D here. For example D8 =IF(B8+D7-C8<0,0,B8+D7-C8)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are correct that my earlier answer is missing a term.  I got some time on a cluster today and worked up a test case.  Below is the revised SQL and setup statements.  It needs a new term which is a window function and since these cannot nest another select layer.  I hope this example helps and I know that working through solving recursive problems on a non-recursive database can be hard.

```
drop table if exists package_volume;

create table package_volume (
        A timestamp encode zstd,
        B int encode zstd,
        C int encode zstd);

insert into package_volume values
('2020-06-26 13:00', 0, 0),
('2020-06-26 14:00', 3500, 0),
('2020-06-26 15:00', 3200, 0),
('2020-06-26 16:00', 6500, 0),
('2020-06-26 17:00', 5200, 50000),
('2020-06-26 18:00', 51000, 50000),
('2020-06-26 19:00', 120000, 50000),
('2020-06-26 20:00', 30000, 50000),
('2020-06-26 21:00', 40000, 50000),
('2020-06-26 22:00', 15000, 50000),
('2020-06-26 23:00', 5500, 50000),
('2020-06-27 00:00', 0, 0);

commit;

select A, B, C, 
        run_tot_pack - run_tot_capacity + sum(unrealized_capacity) over (order by A rows unbounded preceding) as available_volume    
from (
    select A, B, C, run_tot_pack, run_tot_capacity, 
        decode(unrealized_capacity - max(unrealized_capacity) over (order by A rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) < 0, true, 0, 
            unrealized_capacity - max(unrealized_capacity) over (order by A rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding)) as unrealized_capacity
    from (
                    select A, B, C,
                        sum(B) over (order by A rows unbounded preceding) as run_tot_pack,
                        sum(C) over (order by A rows unbounded preceding) as run_tot_capacity,
                        decode(run_tot_pack - run_tot_capacity < 0, true, run_tot_capacity - run_tot_pack, 0) as unrealized_capacity
            from package_volume
        )
)
order by A;
```

Comment: Wow! This is smart. It worked for me.Thank you Bill. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you want but please provide more detail if I'm not answering your question.  To achieve a running total you will need to use the SUM() window function which can sum values over all previous rows.

```
SUM("arrived packages") over ( order by timeinterval rows unbounded preceding )
```

Will give you the running total of "arrived packages".  Now this isn't what you want but let's cover this important function first.

The last requirement is where this gets tricky.  You cannot "bank" unused capacity for later - unused capacity is lost.  So all hours that can process 50,000 packages will.  This will need to be done in 2 steps (query and sub-query) - first find the running total of arrived packages and available throughput. Then take the difference between these but add back in any time there was unused capacity.  Basically take the simple approach and account for the errors as a final adjustment.  Otherwise this becomes a recursive problem and Redshift doesn't like those.  (Sorry, below SQL is untested so take it as notional)

```
select timeinterval, "arrived packages", "throughput per hour",
    run_tot_pack - run_tot_capacity + 
        sum(decode(run_tot_pack - run_tot_capacity < 0, true, run_tot_capacity - run_tot_pack, 0)) over (order by timeinterval rows unbounded preceding) as "available volume"    
from (
    select timeinterval, "arrived packages", "throughput per hour",
        sum("arrived packages") over (order by timeinterval rows unbounded preceding) as run_tot_pack,
        sum("throughput per hour") over (order by timeinterval rows unbounded preceding) as run_tot_capacity
    from <table>
)
order by timeinterval;
```

Comment: Hi Bill, 
Thanks for your reply. I tried this logic outside Redshift, and I think this is close to what I was trying to achieve. The code can generate the first 5 rows correctly, but it starts producing the wrong number after the first zero at column D.